# How to update certain object in state array based on received key from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confused about executing spread operator and using it to update state array like that

```
  todos: [
    {
      id: "1",
      description: "Run",
      completed: "true"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      description: "Pick John",
      completed: "false"
    }]
```

I have objects inside my array, the examples provided after searching are using spread operator to update arrays with single object, how can I update that object with "id" that equals "key" only. My wrong function is

```
markTaskCompleted(e) {
    var key = e._targetInst.key;
    this.setState(
      {
        todoList: // state.todoList is todos variable
          [...this.state.todoList, this.state.todoList.map(task => {
            if (task.id == key) task.completed = "true";
          }) ]
      },
      this.getTodos
    );

  }
```

The result of this array is the same array of todos (spread operator) with array of undefined items. 
I have been googling for some time but couldn't really get it.

Comment: You should be using `prevState` if you need to perform operations on a component's state that relies on a previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of destructuring the array and using map, I typically update a single item's value with a single map that replaces the item I am updating and returns the existing value for all other items. Something like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    todoList: prevState.todoList.map((task) => {
      if (task.id === key) {
        return { ...task, completed: true };
      } else {
        return task;
      }
    }),
  };
});
```

Also, notice that this example passes a function to `this.setState` rather than an object. If you are updating the state based on the previous state (in this example using `todoList` from the previous state) you should use the function method. `setState` is asynchronous and you could get unexpected results from using `this.state` to compute the new state.

Comment: Exactly what I need, Thanks.

Comment: Also, the reason you were getting `undefined` values is that `Array.map` expects you to return something for every value and, if you don't, it will implicitly return `undefined`. All of the `todoList` values where `task.id != key` were not getting eliminated by the if in `map`, just returned as `undefined`. For something like that you can use `Array.filter` or `Array.find` first, but I typically prefer the solution above for this particular situation.

Comment: but how can I make a change with Array.filter? for example if I do this.state.todoList.filter( todo => todo.id == key ) now it will return the object with that condition, but what after ? how should I do the change ?

Comment: If you want to maintain immutability, it is a lot of extra work to use `Array.filter` that `Array.map` is much better suited for. If you don't take advantage of immutability, you can do something `todoList.filter(task => task.id === key).forEach(task => task.completed = true)`. This will modify the existing object instead of creating a new one. React won't know that the object was updated, so you will still need to use setState to trigger the update. This will also break things like React.PureComponent that rely on immutability. I prefer the immutable method in most cases.